# Why does the basic gradient descent not converge for this example?

Tags: convergence, gradient

I have a toy example for a linear regression of the form 
$$y=\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2$$
The data is:

```
x1  x2  y
38  75  70
43  80  70
35  65  96
69  144 137
```

I have tried my own implementation of gradient descent as well as a couple others and even with a $\eta$ (learning rate) of 0.00001, I can't get it to converge.

I have not normalized the numbers.

My question is: If you have a gradient descent program, can you run this example and explain why it does not converge? or does it converge for you (that way I know I am doing things wrong)

The algorithm I have implemented, in pseudo code is:

```
until convergence or max_iterations do
  initialize dw=0 #the delta to update each weight
  for each traning example do
     for each weight i do
         dw[i] = dw[i]+l*(t-o)x[i]
  for each weight i do
     w[i] = w[i]+dw[i]
return w
```

Here's a plot of the data:
[image: Scatterplot of the data]

And if I solve the regression, using R's linear model function, I get the following coefficients: 104.472        4.389       -9.127 
which result in the following plot given different x and y values.
[image: Plane with exactly computer weights]

Comment: Have you plotted the data?  How about plotting a graph of the objective function--that will be highly illuminating.

Comment: I've plotted the error, but  I do not know how to plot the error in terms of the parameters, since there are 3 parameters it would result in a 4d graph, no?

Comment: The contours of the graph are surfaces which you can plot.  You can also learn much about this problem by fixing $\beta_0$ at its optimum value and plotting the objective function in terms of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$.